# Customise Registration Form To Set Specific Customer Group

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, customer-group, customer-registration

We currently have a registration form but we want to change one of the checkboxes to give it additional functionality so that it changes the group the customer will be put into when they register from the default one to a special loyalty one.

I've looked at a few solutions online but I haven't been able to find one that does this exactly, most seem to create a dropdown to select customer group but we just want this one checkbox to change it.

Comment: ok, so which customer group you want to select while tick on checkbox ?

Comment: @Dotsquares when the checkbox is selected we want it to select the group called loyalty which is group id 4 and if it's not then it should put them into the default group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change customer group during registration by some request checkbox you can:

Create plugin for `\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface` after method `createAccount` and on update $customer group based on `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface`

Or create observer on event `customer_register_success` and update customer group.

You don't need to install any additional extension for this. If you have an issue with creating plugin or observer, I can prove the example. Let me know

**[UPDATE]**

In my example `Acme` like vendor name, `StackExchange` - module name

**1. Register extension**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/registration.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Acme_StackExchange', __DIR__);
```

**2. Create module declaration**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/module.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Acme_StackExchange">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**3. Create Dependency Injection for set plugin**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Customer_Api_AccountManagementPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Customer\Api\AccountManagementPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**4. Create plugin**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Customer/Api/AccountManagementPlugin.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Customer\Api;

use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class AccountManagementPlugin
{
    protected RequestInterface            $request;
    protected CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }

    public function afterCreateAccount(
        AccountManagementInterface $subject,
        CustomerInterface $result
    ): CustomerInterface {
        // check if checkbox value set
        if ($this->request->getParam('your_checkbox_name')) {
            // set custom group
            $result->setGroupId('GROUP_ID');
            // save customer data
            $this->customerRepository->save($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**5. Run setup upgrade**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

*References:*

- [Plugins](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/plugins/)
- [Events and observers](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/events-and-observers/)
- [About component file structure](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/prepare/component-file-structure/)
- [Modules and extensibility](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/architecture/modules/)

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm new when it comes to Magento, so I don't know how to make plugins or observers - but I'm willing to learn. I've seen a lot of people talking about observers in other threads but not seen anyone say where they go though

Comment: You can find a lot of examples here. See updated answer and hope this will help

Comment: How this works in graphQL? I am using createCustomer mutation.